# How to create Yacc/Lex rules for embedding C source code snippets?

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I'm implementing a custom parser generator with embedded lexer and parser to parse HTTP headers in an event-driven state machine way. Here's some definitions the eventual parser generator could consume to parse a single header field without CRLF at the end:

```
token host<prio=1> = "[Hh][Oo][Ss][Tt]" ;
token ospace = "[ \t]*" ;
token htoken = "[-!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z]+" ;
token hfield = "[\t\x20-\x7E\x80-\xFF]*" ;
token space = " " ;
token htab = "\t" ;
token colon = ":" ;

obsFoldStart = 1*( space | htab ) ;
hdrField =
  obsFoldStart hfield
| host colon ospace hfield<print>
| htoken colon ospace hfield
  ;
```

The lexer is based on a maximal munch rule and the tokens are dynamically turned on and off depending on the context, so there is no conflict between `htoken` and `hfield`, and the priority value resolves the conflict between `host` and `htoken`. I'm planning to implement the parser as LL(1) table parser. I haven't yet decided if I'll implement regexp token matching by simulating the nondeterministic finite automaton or go all the way to exploding it to a deterministic finite automaton.

Now, I would like to include some C source code in my parser generator input:

```
hdrField =
  obsFoldStart hfield
| host {
  parserState->userdata.was_host = 1;
} colon ospace hfield<print>
| htoken {
  parserState->userdata.was_host = 0;
} colon ospace hfield
  ;
```

What I need thus is some way to read text tokens that end when the same amount of `}` characters are read than the amount of `{` characters read.

How to do this? I'm handling comments using `BEGIN(COMMENTS)` and `BEGIN(INITIAL)` but I don't believe such a strategy would work for embedded C source. Also, the comment handling could complicate the embedded C source code handling a lot, because I don't believe a single token can have a comment in the middle of it.

Basically, I need the embedded C language snippet as a C string I can store to my data structures.

Comment: I'm actually generating a custom version of lex+yacc using lex and yacc... Yes, I am aware that lex and yacc do produce C code.

Comment: I missed the "generator" in _I'm implementing a custom parser generator_. Sorry. For a parser generator, I wrote once one, which produces a recursive descent parser (in C++) - quite easy to implement. For disambiguation, it supports back-tracking to a limited amount. That was sufficient for all practical languages we had to process upto now. (Look-up 2 is the most we got.) For the critical thing - generating the DFA out of reg. expressions, I involved `flex` (just generating lex sources). It's too perfect and too convenient to replace it by something own (although I would like to do it 1 day).

Comment: Unfortunately, recursive descent won't work here as it has to process input in an event-drive state machine way, incrementally. So, the input might appear in small chunks, and the parser generator needs to stop temporarily at the end of a chunk and re-start its operation from the same point at the start of the next chunk. Unfortunately, C language doesn't have coroutines, so the only way this is going to work is to implement it as a state machine, not as a recursive descent parser. I already have Python prototype for LL(1) parsing.

Comment: ...and oh, flex and yacc won't work because (1) flex and yacc don't work in unison by dynamically turning tokens on and off, and (2) for some reason flex and yacc aren't implemented as incrementally fed state machines...

Comment: I agree your point. However, I think you could stop the recursive descent parser at any point where it awaits a new token (e.g. by a callback). After having received new input, it could return to that point. At any point, the parser may produce output. So, I don't see your concerns. (But, this doesn't mean that I want to critize your decision or encourage to do something else instead.) ;-)

Comment: Yes, that could be one solution but given that I already have LL(1) prototype in Python, I think I'll choose the LL(1) approach.

Comment: Actually, the parser of my parser generator is implemented in its own language. (I did some kind of boot-strapping for convenience, proof of concept, and just for fun.) As source code may contain C/C++ code which has to be written into actions (similar like in `yacc`), I did the resp. parts in `flex` syntax. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Scheff Sound like you could answer this question! However, I decided to use flex/yacc for implementing parser of my parser generator instead of bootstrapping it somehow and then using my own language... Yet using flex syntax is common for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I took some of the generated lex code and made it self standing.

I hope, it's OK that I used C++ code although I recognized the [c](/questions/tagged/c) only. IMHO, it concerns only the not so 
relevant parts of this sample code. (Memory management in C is much more tedious than simply delegating this to `std::string`.)

`scanC.l`:

```
%{

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifdef _WIN32
/// disables #include <unistd.h>
#define YY_NO_UNISTD_H
#endif // _WIN32

// buffer for collected C/C++ code
static std::string cCode;
// counter for braces
static int nBraces = 0;

%}

/* Options */

/* make never interactive (prevent usage of certain C functions) */
%option never-interactive
/* force lexer to process 8 bit ASCIIs (unsigned characters) */
%option 8bit
/* prevent usage of yywrap */
%option noyywrap


EOL ("\n"|"\r"|"\r\n")
SPC ([ \t]|"\\"{EOL})*
LITERAL "\""("\\".|[^\\"])*"\""

%s CODE

%%

<INITIAL>"{" { cCode = '{'; nBraces = 1; BEGIN(CODE); }
<INITIAL>. |
<INITIAL>{EOL} { std::cout << yytext; }
<INITIAL><<EOF>> { return 0; }

<CODE>"{" {
  cCode += '{'; ++nBraces;
  //updateFilePos(yytext, yyleng);
} break;
<CODE>"}" {
  cCode += '}'; //updateFilePos(yytext, yyleng);
  if (!--nBraces) {
    BEGIN(INITIAL);
    //return new Token(filePosCCode, Token::TkCCode, cCode.c_str());
    std::cout << '\n'
      << "Embedded C code:\n"
      << cCode << "// End of embedded C code\n";
  }
} break;

<CODE>"/*" { // C comments
  cCode += "/*"; //_filePosCComment = _filePos;
  //updateFilePos(yytext, yyleng);
  char c1 = ' ';
  do {
    char c0 = c1; c1 = yyinput();
    switch (c1) {
      case '\r': break;
      case '\n':
        cCode += '\n'; //updateFilePos(&c1, 1);
        break;
      default:
        if (c0 == '\r' && c1 != '\n') {
          c0 = '\n'; cCode += '\n'; //updateFilePos(&c0, 1);
        } else {
          cCode += c1; //updateFilePos(&c1, 1);
        }
    }
    if (c0 == '*' && c1 == '/') break;
  } while (c1 != EOF);
  if (c1 == EOF) {
    //ErrorFile error(_filePosCComment, "'/*' without '*/'!");
    //throw ErrorFilePrematureEOF(_filePos);
    std::cerr << "ERROR! '/*' without '*/'!\n";
    return -1;
  }
} break;
<CODE>"//"[^\r\n]* | /* C++ one-line comments */
<CODE>"'"("\\".|[^\\'])+"'" | /*"/* C/C++ character constants */
<CODE>{LITERAL} | /* C/C++ string constants */
<CODE>"#"[^\r\n]* | /* preprocessor commands */
<CODE>[ \t]+ | /* non-empty white space */
<CODE>[^\r\n] { // any other character except EOL
  cCode += yytext;
  //updateFilePos(yytext, yyleng);
} break;
<CODE>{EOL} { // special handling for EOL
  cCode += '\n';
  //updateFilePos(yytext, yyleng);
} break;
<CODE><<EOF>> { // premature EOF
  //ErrorFile error(_filePosCCode,
  //  compose("%1 '{' without '}'!", _nBraces));
  //_errorManager.add(error);
  //throw ErrorFilePrematureEOF(_filePos);
  std::cerr << "ERROR! Premature end of input. (Not enough '}'s.)\n";
}

%%

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  return yylex();
}
```

A sample text to scan `scanC.txt`:

```
Hello juhist.

The text without braces doesn't need to have any syntax.
It just echoes the characters until it finds a block:
{ // the start of C code
  // a C++ comment
  /* a C comment
   * (Remember that nested /*s are not supported.)
   */
  #define MAX 1024
  static char buffer[MAX] = "", empty="\"\"";

  /* It is important that tokens are recognized to a limited amount.
   * Otherwise, it would be too easy to fool the scanner with }}}
   * where they have no meaning.
   */
  char *theSameForStringConstants = "}}}";
  char *andCharConstants = '}}}';

  int main() { return yylex(); }
}
This code should be just copied
(with a remark that the scanner recognized the C code a such.)

Greetings, Scheff.
```

Compiled and tested on [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ flex --version
flex 2.6.4

$ flex -o scanC.cc scanC.l

$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.3.0

$ g++ -std=c++11 -o scanC scanC.cc

$ ./scanC < scanC.txt
Hello juhist.

The text without braces doesn't need to have any syntax.
It just echoes the characters until it finds a block:

Embedded C code:
{ // the start of C code
  // a C++ comment
  /* a C comment
   * (Remember that nested /*s are not supported.)
   */
  #define MAX 1024
  static char buffer[MAX] = "", empty="\"\"";

  /* It is important that tokens are recognized to a limited amount.
   * Otherwise, it would be too easy to fool the scanner with }}}
   * where they have no meaning.
   */
  char *theSameForStringConstants = "}}}";
  char *andCharConstants = '}}}';

  int main() { return yylex(); }

}// End of embedded C code
This code should be just copied
(with a remark that the scanner recognized the C code a such.)

Greetings, Scheff.
$
```

**Notes:**

1. This is taken from a helper tool (not for selling). Hence, this is not bullet-proof but just good enough for productive code.
2. What I saw when adapting it: The line continuation of pre-processor lines is not handled.
3. It's surely possible to fool the tool with a creative combination of macros with unbalanced `{` `}` – something we would never do in pur productive code (see 1.).

So, it might be at least a start for further development.

To check this against a C lex specification, I have [ANSI C grammar, Lex specification](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html) at hand, though it's 22 years old. (There are probably newer ones available matching the current standards.)

Comment: Thanks! I indeed figured it out while you were writing the answer, and I used the same approach of using lex states and an integer for the number of braces. Great minds think alike, or so it has been said...